# Ejecutar comando remotamente exec_command en Python

Tags: python, docker, ssh

Estoy intentando ejecutar un comando remotamente vía ssh.
El comando a ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
docker exec -it gitlab runner "token = User.find_by_username('username').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes:[:api,:read_user,:sudo,:read_repository],name:'Pruebatoken');token.set_token('xxxxxxxxxx0123456789');token.save!"
```

Y el código que estoy probando es:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
comando = "docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rails runner token = User.find_by_username('username').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes: [:api, :read_user, :sudo, :read_repository], name: 'PruebaToken'); token.set_token('aaaaaaaaaa2222222222'); token.save!"
client_stdin, client_stdout, client_stderr = client.exec_command(comando)
lines = client_stdout.readlines()
errors = client_stderr.readlines()
for l in lines:
    print ('line', l)

for e in errors:
    print ('error', e)

client.close()
```

No me ejecuta el comando y me da error error bash: -c: línia 0: error de sintaxi cerca del elemento inesperado `('

Creo que el problema está en el formato del comando. Cómo lo debería poner?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Falta una cremilla en `User.find_by_username('username)`?

Comment: @CandidMoe ha sido error al traspasar el código. Sí que tengo la comilla simple en mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando que estás pasando a `client_exec()` es el que defines aquí:

```
comando = "docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rails runner token = User.find_by_username('username').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes: [:api, :read_user, :sudo, :read_repository], name: 'PruebaToken'); token.set_token('aaaaaaaaaa2222222222'); token.save!"
```

En ese comando faltan las comillas que deberían ir alrededor del comando a ejecutar el el contenedor. Es decir, todo lo que va tras runner.

Por otro lado, no sé que lenguaje es el que usan los comandos dentro de esa cadena, pero la admiración al final de `save!` me parece sospechosa.

En todo caso, sería así (aprovecho para ponerlo en varias líneas para mejor legibilidad, pero Python concatenará todas esas cadenas en una sola, al ir separadas por espacios o retornos de carro dentro de unos paréntesis)

```
comando = (
    "docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rails runner "
       "\"token = User.find_by_username('username')"
         ".personal_access_tokens"
         ".create(scopes: [:api, :read_user, :sudo, :read_repository], "
                  "name: 'PruebaToken');"
       "token.set_token('aaaaaaaaaa2222222222');"
       "token.save!\""
)
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado tal como indicas. Gracias!